# Difference between "Urteilen" and "Beurteilen"

Tags: word-usage, difference, comparison

What would be the difference between `Urteilen` and `Beurteilen`?

The translations both seem to be similar and I am aware that the `be-`prefix adds a sense of the verb inflicted on something.

However I would like to know how they are commonly used and in what context?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GermanSE! What dictionaries did you check? [urteilen](https://www.dict.cc/?s=urteilen) and [beurteilen](https://www.dict.cc/?s=beurteilen) only have `to judge` as a common translation. Can you specify an example sentence where you are unsure about the translation?

Answer (score 3):

**urteilen**
... is almost exclusively used in the meaning of *sentence/decide/rule* in connection with court/judge decisions. The object is either of rather general nature, e.g. : *Das Gericht urteilte im Fall Müller gegen Meier.* or the actual decision is introduced as: *Das Gericht urteilte, dass...*

In order to express the actual sentence often *verurteilen* ist used: *Das Gericht verurteilte den Angeklagten zu zwei Jahren Gefängnis.*

**beurteilen**
...has the meaning of *assess, evaluate*,  e.g of a situation, a study, an experiment.

Comment: I agree. What is interesting, though, is that the noun "Urteil", which is the source of both, can also be used in the sense of a personal evaluation: "nach meinem Urteil".

Comment: this is great..! Thank you so much..! Really appreciate this. :)